# Dropping files into Excel form to be loaded in Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, forms, sharepoint

This is what I'm trying to do. Is it possible?

Drop a file from local windows explorer into an excel file in sharepoint, through an excel form, to be loaded into an specific folder in sharepoint, the folder folder would be defined by the entries in other fields of the excel form.

Comment: Drag/drop: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-drag-and-drop-file-to-userform-then-save-it-using-data-from-userform-fields.1161424/    As for saving the files to SP folders, you can open the file in Excel and save it to SP, in the location you choose.